# Where do 5 or more U.S. counties meet in a single point?

Tags: usa, where-on-earth

The other day I was looking at a county map near my home in NE Georgia. I noticed that there is a point where 4 counties meet - Hall, Jackson, Gwinnett, and Barrow (see screenshot).
[image]

This made me wonder if there are any locations in the U.S. where 5 or more counties meet at a single geographic point? If so, where?

Comment: interesting that the point of Jackson, Barrow & Gwinnett is tangential to the _edge_ of Hall, and that Hall doesn't have a point there.

Comment: Do you mean *within* a single state, or can this happen at the edge/corner of multiple (2+) states? By definition [Four Corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Corners) must have at least one county each from AZ, CO, NM, UT. Also I'm thinking of county and state boundaries which occur inside (large) lakes or rivers.

Comment: There's a [near quintipoint](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/932548) in Texas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a geography trivia question that has nothing to do with travelling.

Comment: But what if I wish to travel to this point, @DavidRicherby? Wouldn't I first need to establish where this exists, if indeed it exists at all?

Comment: @smci - it can be inter- or intra-state. Your example of Four Corners is a good one where four counties touch.

Comment: @Will By that reasoning, any question about any possible place on earth is a travel question. You don't make a travel question just by adding "And can I travel there?" onto the end of it: that's just [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about). (Especially when the original question says nothing about travelling and "Can I travel there?" only gets added once somebody says it's off-topic.)

Comment: @Rob I've no idea what you mean by "Just VTC, no Santa" but note that I _did_ just vote to close but I was then asked to justify that, so I responded.

Comment: If you're curious about other countries, [the best multipoint seems to be on Sicily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadripoint#Multipoints_of_greater_numerical_complexity)

Comment: @Rob \*shrug\* The asker proposed changing their question in response to my comment, so I explained why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Don't invalidate the answers is the answer, and how they plan to massage it another question. I VTC'd OT to Meta. It's probably not suitable for GIS.SE or EarthSciences.SE either. Sometimes there's just no place for something, save for the chatroom. Really says something that OT Q&A's earn the posters 200 rep while *better* Q&A's starve, but that part of this comment wanders OT.

Comment: I can see how traveling to a point where 4 countries or at least 4 US states meet could be interesting. But 4 counties? There's nothing interesting at the county level.

Comment: It might not interest YOU to travel there, @JonathanReez. But that makes one of us;)

Comment: @Rob That same link has a quintipoint in Florida.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Lake Okeechobee in Florida is the best known location in the US where this happens, according to the [Twelve Mile Circle website](https://www.howderfamily.com/blog/lake-okeechobees-five-counties/):

> Looking at Lake Okeechobee on this Microsoft Encarta map clearly shows a point where five different Florida counties come together at a single point: Glades; Hendry; Palm Beach, Martin and Okeechobee. There is no other spot in the United States where this occurs.
>
> [image]

The blog states that this is the only location in the US; as far as we can tell that's correct, even though Ron Maupin found [another near-occurrence in Texas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138076/28333).

Comment: "Microsoft Encarta" now there's a name I haven't heard in a long time. A _long_ time.

Comment: The only point *within* a single state. But can this happen at the edge/corner of multiple states?

Comment: "_Lake Okeechobee in Florida is the only location in the US where this happens_" That is untrue. See my answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Nearly is nearly enough.

Comment: @RonMaupin's answer is incorrect: the five counties there come very close but don't all meet at a point.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar my goodness that brings back memories when I was traveling around with Microsoft Streets & Trips and no GPS, and still I hardly ever got lost.

Answer (score 12):

There are five counties in Florida that meet in the middle of [Lake Okeechobee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Okeechobee).

I haven't been able to find more, but the Wikipedia article implies that there may be more.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadripoint#Multipoints_of_greater_numerical_complexity

Comment: [This article from Condé Nast](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/sicily-mount-etna-is-the-worlds-only-decipoint) states that the Florida "quintipoint" is the only one in the United States.  (Note that the Wikipedia article only implies that there are others elsewhere in the world, not necessarily in the USA.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, that is not true. See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

In Texas, there is a point where five counties meet:

[image]

The (roughly) triangle shaped county is [Delta County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_County,_Texas). The county to the north is [Lamar County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamar_County,_Texas). The county to the south is [Hopkins county](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins_County,_Texas). The two counties to the east are  [Red River County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_River_County,_Texas) (NE) and [Franklin County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_County,_Texas) (SE).

A better picture:

[image]

Comment: If you search [this site](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/932548) (originally linked in a comment on the question) for "near-quintipoint", you'll find it claims this Texas situation is not an actual quintipoint. Can you address this?

Comment: [Relevant image](https://community.wolfram.com/c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=4645almostquintpoint.png&userId=46025) from the web site linked by the previous comment.

Comment: [Texas DOT](http://www.dot.state.tx.us/apps-cg/grid_search/_includes/countymapbook/Pages/504.pdf) map (pdf) showing the "near-quintipoint" hook at the eastern end of Delta county, albeit not as exaggerated as with the Wolfram-generated maps.

Comment: @Angew, if you ever visit there, you will find the point where the five counties meet, and if you ever go fishing there, you will have game wardens from the five different counties checking your fishing license.

Comment: Here is some [GIS data](http://gis-txdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/959bede33a9e445896d97d39be7bce23_0/data?geometry=-95.337%2C33.373%2C-95.287%2C33.386) that also shows a _near_ quintipoint.

Comment: @RonMaupin The DOT map clearly shows that there is _no_ point where the five counties meet. In particular, the borders of Lamar and Franklin Counties do not meet anywhere. Wikipedia's pages on the two counties also don't list them among "adjacent counties" ([Lamar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamar_County,_Texas), [Franklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_County,_Texas)).

Comment: @JPhi1618 In the (admittedly few) jurisdictions where I've had reason to pay close attention to boundaries, GIS data is not authoritative. The legal boundaries of anything are given as text descriptions, e.g., "from the junction of road X and road Y, north 1000 meters, then west..." GIS data is *usually* accurate, but sometimes contains mistakes or mountweasels. For example, Google's GIS data and satellite imagery for the Four Corners region is out of registration by several tens of meters.

Comment: @TKK Ironically, the positions of the borders of Arizona, Utah, Colorado and New Mexico at Four Corners are legally specified as the lines of latitude and longitude. It's also legally specified that the marker marks the spot where they meet. But the marker is several tens of meters off the true position, due to the difficulty of pre-GPS surveying in the mountains.

Comment: I don’t understand why this answer hasn’t been deleted; it’s quite clearly, blatantly wrong. This is exactly the issue with the HNQ; an incorrect answer to an off topic question, both with absurd numbers of votes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure about that. Surveyed lines have a lot of legal significance. A law may have been passed authorizing surveyors to survey the borders of the states along those lines of latitude and longitude, but the lines that were *actually* surveyed and marked are the legal borders of the states. The monument is in the right place by definition, and any maps based on the originally intended borders are wrong.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This actually went to the Supreme Court as [New Mexico v. Colorado](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/267/30/). The original surveyed borders are the legal borders, despite later surveys discovering the magnitude of the error.

Comment: @Tim Nobody has offered *authoritative* evidence that this answer is wrong.

Comment: @TKK I uhh, what??? You need to give evidence that you are right, we don’t have to prove you wrong! Aside from that, Wolfram Alpha, the DOT map, Wikipedia and GIS data, and you’ve offered two, old, low quality maps. Heck, the first map looks to me to *disagree* with you; look at the additional pixel in the bottom left corner of the top right quadrant. That suggests to me (backed up by the aforementioned rebuttals) that the bottom left and top right counties (and top left and bottom right) don’t touch (which is exactly what all the comments above claim).

Comment: @Tim You seem to have mistaken me for the person who posted this answer. I'm just adding what I know about what *kinds of sources* are authoritative when it comes to boundary lines. GIS maps, even those produced by government agencies, are rarely if ever authoritative. In the US, whenever actual surveyed lines differ from the intended boundaries, the actual surveyed lines almost always take legal precedence. The actual surveyed lines are then described in text form identifying survey markers and landmarks, and *that* is the only kind of source that could disprove this answer.

Comment: @TKK my apologies, yes. However, it is not on us to use the text-described survey lines to disprove this answer, it is on the OP to prove their answer with the aforementioned. As it is, both the OP and the commenters have used non-official sources.

Comment: @Tim True. I admit I'm probably unfairly biased against GIS data, because in my experience (like Google's mistake I mentioned above, and working with official BLM maps) the quality of publicly available GIS data in general is extremely bad, and too many people mistake its precision for accuracy. I'm more inclined to trust where some podunk Game & Fish officer thinks the border is.

Comment: @Tim the proper course of action for an incorrect answer is not to delete it but to downvote it.